# Launch shiny app with every new restart of R automatically

Tags: r, server, shiny

I have a rather large shiny app, where I execute longer computations, deployed on a local server. 
The actual problem is that the RAM is not totally cleared with calls like `gc()` and `rm()`  . After a few runs the RAM is not sufficient anymore and a restart of R is needed with `.rs.restartR()`.

My approach so far was simply to launch the app with an `.Rprofile` and the "first" function like

```
.First <- function(){

  setwd("directory")

  shiny::runApp()}
```

I also tried to call the app in inside a script with `source()` instead of directly with `shiny::runApp()`

When opening RStudio it gives me a blank window but the app is called nevertheless.
I could live with the blank version of RStudio, but the computation takes a lot longer than normal (so long that i dont even know if it finishes at all).

Any suggestions of what could be the problem would be grateful.

Comment: why not getting a shiny server or rstudio connect? There are community versions

Comment: *"the RAM is not totally cleared"* suggests compiled (dll) code and memory leaks. I'd strongly suggest you put some effort into identifying if not resolving that problem. Having said that, you will find auto-execution instructions within [`?Startup`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/Startup). If this were me, I'd be using the open-source shiny server in a docker container with memory limits and `restart: "always"`.

Comment: thanks four your comments. If I cant manage it,  my last option is shiny server in a docker container. I found a small memory leak but R keeps to be blank and slow. It must be the combination of starting shiny in an .Rprofile